# I got Marquee Label error in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift2, uicollectionviewcell, marquee, tvos9.1

I got this error when i scrolls fast Left to Right or Right to Left.

> " Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13cf0d300"

I have implemented the code. given below image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `completionHandler` gets called on the main queue? If not, try wrapping the code in the `completionHandler` with a

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    if thumbnailsURL == url {
        // Your animation code
    }
}
```